# SQL Server 2012 locate backup file not displaying file structure

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I have recently installed SQL Server 2012 Express. When I try and restore a previous database, the "Locate Backup File" box is not displaying correctly:

[image]

When I maximise the window, it looks like this:

[image]

Which means that I can't select a backup. But has anyone else had this issue and how was it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix the UI problem, but if you want to restore your database, run this code.

```
RESTORE DATABASE yourDatabaseName   
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\yourDatabaseName.bak';
```